# Unexpected <type> at the end of statement

Tags: go

The Go code is below.

Error Message: syntax error: unexpected float64 at end of statement in line 9.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    v float64 = math.Pow(x,n) // line 9
    if v<lim {
        return v
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%g >= %g\n", v, lim)
    }   
    return lim 
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(
        pow(3, 2, 10),
        pow(3, 2, 20),
    )   
}
```

I don't know what is wrong. Who know that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Change line 9 to either of statements below:

```
v := math.Pow(x,n) // implicit type declaration and assignment
```

or

```
var v float64 = math.Pow(x,n) // explicit type declaration and assignment
```

See [short variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

Answer (score 4):

Variable declaration in Go

**static**
var var_name data_type = value

or

**dynamic:**
var_name := value

In your case at line 9 you have missed both standard